# creating a chart for my website

Tags: php, javascript, html, charts

I'm trying to create a chart for my website. It will be a simple line chart showing my funds remaining (left/vertical) and the date (bottom/horizontal). It will be updated daily.

What is the simplest method for creating a line chart for a website?

Since it will be updated daily, I would like to find a simple way to add in a new number (funds remaining) each day and have it update without much work on my end. I don't have much time to learn other languages and technologies so I would like to have it up and running quickly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's [Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) will allow you to get decent looking graphs created quickly with minimal effort. By feeding in different data each day you can have a new graph every day without having to make any changes to the code that handles generating the graph.

Google's Chart API uses javascript to generate the graph. If you're looking to generate the graph on the server side with PHP, and then have a look at the [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) library for PHP.

Comment: It looks like Google's Chart API does the job, but updating it seems very manual. I have to manually specify the number of rows (add one to it every time I make an entry) and manually enter in the date 11/12/11. In an ideal situation, I could have it detect the date automatically and update the chart given the new number. Maybe I could make a php script to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We use Highcharts JS for all of our datamining coverage graphs. You can see examples of it here:

http://hhsmithy.com/coverage

I highly recommend checking them out.

http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score -1):

I use RGraph ( https://www.rgraph.net ). But I am a little biased - I make it! Here's an example of a very basic line chart:

```
<script>
    data = [8,7,6,4,9,5,6,7,9]; // <-- Change this for your data

    myChart = new RGraph.Line({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: data,
        options: {
        }
    }).draw();
</script>
```